# How to print next to each other instead of vertically?

Tags: c++, arrays, output

How do I make this so that the numbers 1-10 print out next to the sales, instead of the sales under the 1-10?

```
void Bonus::calcAndDisplay(int salesArray[10][4], double rate)
{
    for (int num = 1; num < 11; num += 1)
    {

        cout << num << "\n";
    }

    for (int row = 0; row < 10; row += 1)
    {

        for (int column = 0; column < 4; column += 1)
        {
            totSales += salesArray[row][column];
        }   
        cout << totSales << "\n";
        totSales = 0;
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: What is totSales? In general, combine the two for loops. nun=row+1 in your case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fundamentally there is a structural problem with your code.

Once you have written to the console and moved on to the next line you cannot go back and write further on that line. (In general)

You need to re-consider your algorithm  so that it writes the Number, sales and bonus in a single action rather than separating your loops into Loop1, loop2 then loop3.

I have taken the main for loop and  moved your line that prints the COUNT inside the loop.

```
for (int row = 0; row < 10; row += 1)
    {
        cout << row << "\t";
        for (int column = 0; column < 4; column += 1)
        {
            totSales += salesArray[row][column];
        }
        cout << totSales << "\n";
        totSales = 0;
    }
```

Note: \t is a tab feed... \t\t is two tab feeds.

I haven't tested the code but from here you should be able to make it work

Comment: ok now im having trouble getting the salesBonus in there, i try and do salesBonus = totSales * rate in the same place as the totSales calculation, and print it in the same place as the totSales but it's not working, I also need to have two decimal places on the bonus but when i do set precision right before that print statement it does nothing but add zeros before the row output?

Comment: @David Don't you mean `\t` is tab ??

Comment: @SrinivasSuresh,  Thank you, yes I did mean \t instead of /t.   I had a Brain Phart as I was writing that in.. I have corrected the original post to reflect the correct information.